# Terenary operator not working with conditional assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried writing

```py
age = 22
message = "Eligible" if age>=22 else message = "not eligible"
print(message)
```

The above code is failing with the error

```
SyntaxError: cannot assign to conditional expression
```

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: The ternary operator operates on _expressions_, not arbitrary statements like assignments. You want to write `message = "Eligible" if age>=22 else "not eligible"`.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to get rid off the `message =` after the else statement.

```py
message = "Eligible" if age>=22 else "not eligible"
```

Ternary operators are structed like:

```
variable = [value on_true] if [expression] else [value on_false]
```